# ASUS VN248H-P Monitor green static/speckling over HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi

The monitor gets a kind of green static while using HDMI cords. Some cords work better than others, but they all have this speckling of green on dark images.

[image: Photo of the monitor connected with a HDMI cable]

But when using VGA, it's fine.

[image: Photo of the monitor connected with a VGAcable]

The green static goes away if I change the resolution to 1080i from 1080p, but that gives the new problem of the monitor image "vibrates" up and down.

I need to use HDMI, can anybody shed some light onto the cause of this?

Comment: the images are not accessible, upload them on some public hosting sites like imgur

Comment: maybe it is a misconfigured graphics card? try plugging in the monitor straight into the motherboard instead of a graphics card.

Comment: Direct to motherboard is not working either.